# Creating a java client for secured esb proxy

Tags: security, wso2, wso2-esb

I want to create a java client for **version proxy service** present in wso2 esb. **I have secured the version proxy with Username Token Authentication scenario.** Now i have started creating the java client to invoke this secured proxy service and my client code is:

```
package org.wso2.carbon.security.ws;

import org.apache.axis2.addressing.EndpointReference;
import org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContext;
import org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory;
import org.apache.axis2.description.AxisBinding;
import org.apache.axis2.description.AxisEndpoint;
import org.apache.axis2.rpc.client.RPCServiceClient;
import org.apache.neethi.Policy;

import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Map;

public class HelloServiceClient {

    static {
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "/path/to/keystore" + File.separator+ "wso2carbon.jks");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "wso2carbon");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            int securityScenario = getSecurityScenario();

            String repository = "/path/to/repo" + File.separator + "repository";

            ConfigurationContext confContext =
                    ConfigurationContextFactory.
                            createConfigurationContextFromFileSystem(repository, null);

            String endPoint = "HelloServiceHttpSoap12Endpoint";
            if(securityScenario == 1){
                endPoint = "HelloServiceHttpsSoap12Endpoint";   // scenario 1 uses HelloServiceHttpsSoap12Endpoint
            }

            RPCServiceClient dynamicClient =
                    new RPCServiceClient(confContext,
                                         new URL("http://pc213712:8281/services/Version?wsdl"),
                                         new QName("http://version.services.core.carbon.wso2.org", "Version"),
                                         endPoint);

            //Engage Modules
            dynamicClient.engageModule("rampart");
            dynamicClient.engageModule("addressing");

            //TODO : Change the port to monitor the messages through TCPMon
            if(securityScenario != 1){
                dynamicClient.getOptions().setTo(new EndpointReference("http://pc213712:8281/services/Version/"));
            }

            //Get the policy from the binding and append the rampartconfig assertion
            Map endPoints = dynamicClient.getAxisService().getEndpoints();
            AxisBinding axisBinding = ((AxisEndpoint) endPoints.values().iterator().next()).getBinding();
            Policy policy = axisBinding.getEffectivePolicy();
            **policy.addAssertion(RampartConfigBuilder.createRampartConfig(securityScenario));**
            axisBinding.applyPolicy(policy);

            //Invoke the service
            Object[] returnArray = dynamicClient.invokeBlocking(new QName("http://www.wso2.org/types","greet"),
                                                                new Object[]{"Alice"},
                                                                new Class[]{String.class});

            System.out.println((String) returnArray[0]);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static int getSecurityScenario() {
        int scenarioNumber = 0;
        while (scenarioNumber < 1 || scenarioNumber > 15) {
            System.out.print("Insert the security scenario no : ");
            String inputString = readOption();
            try {
                scenarioNumber = new Integer(inputString);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("invalid input, insert a integer between 1 and 15");
            }
            if(scenarioNumber < 1 || scenarioNumber > 15){
                System.out.println("Scenario number should be between 1 and 15");
            }
        }
        return scenarioNumber;
    }
    private static String readOption() {
        try {
            BufferedReader console = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String str;
            while ((str = console.readLine()).equals("")) {
            }
            return str;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

But in the above code i am struck at one line that is :

```
policy.addAssertion(RampartConfigBuilder.createRampartConfig(securityScenario));
```

Here in my rampart_core jar I am getting **RampartConfigBuilder** class but inside this class there is no such method called **createRampartConfig**. So i am unable to create Rampart configurations. What can i do to solve this issue? looking forward to your solutions. Thanks in advance

Comment: that `RampartConfigBuilder` class seems like it could be a local utility and not part of the Rampart distribution.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to Create Rampart configurations i.e setting username passwords etc so that i can invoke my secured proxy service called verison

Comment: This rampart sample may help: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/axis/axis2/java/rampart/tags/v1.6.1/modules/rampart-samples/policy/sample01/

Comment: The problem is except wso2 exposed services, all other services is getting autenticated from the client as given in this URL http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/axis/axis2/java/rampart/tags/v1.6.1/modules/rampart-samples/policy/sample01/  but when i hit esb's proxy service(secured) with the above client code. It gives me exception

Comment: What exception are you getting?

Comment: Are you trying one of the samples that comes with the ESB?  If so, which one?

Comment: No we are not trying any of the samples mentioned in wso2 esb's document. We have made the echo proxy service secured using username token and now we want to access it through java client but unfortunately we are unable to access the secured service through our java code

Comment: If you list the exact steps you have performed so far then I can replicate your environment and maybe help.  E.g. (1) download esb 4.6.0.  (2) unzip, startup, login (3) select Main>Services:List>echo (4) list all the other steps ...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32792/discussion-between-roy-and-chris)

Comment: (1) download esb 4.6.0. (2) unzip, startup, login (3) select Main>Services:List>echo (4)Click on Unsecured link of echo service (5) Enable Security>Yes (6) Select UsernameToken in Basic Scenarios Tab (7) Click on next (8) Select admin as User Groups (9) Then click finish

Comment: Now my secured proxy is created and the above code that i have written is to invoke this secured service which is not working.

Comment: I have put some sample code here: https://bitbucket.org/snowch/wso2-esb-echo-ut-client